# VBA Worksheets.Copy method changes comma style behaviour

Tags: vba, excel

I used the following code to copy two sheets from my workbook to another file:

```
    Worksheets(Array("One", "Two")).Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook
         .SaveAs Filename:=dir & "New_" & d & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
         .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
```

But it seems to change the way negative numbers are treated by comma style. In the original workbook, pressing the physical "Comma style" button would make a number look like -734,343.54 (with the minus sign at the far left). While in the new file it gives it parentheses, i.e. (734,343.54).

Setting the style as "Accounting" gives the same results for both workbooks, that is with the minus sign, except it includes the currency, which I do not need. How could I make sure that comma style does not change it's behaviour?

**Update (more understandable code):**

```
Sub test()
    Worksheets(Array("Sheet1")).Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook
         .SaveAs Filename:="New" & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
         .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What was the file format before? I can't imagine that is the problem. Have you changed somehow the display format for negative numbers?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the above code. Works as expected for me. What version of Excel are you using btw?

Comment: @Smanis - You might have changed the formats of the original sheet , try to remove all formats from the original and check again.

Comment: I tried closing Excel, then created a new blank .xlsm document, typed -734343.54 into a random cell formatted as "General" and pressed "Comma style", which made it into -734,343.54. Then I ran my code, and once again it saved a new file with the cell formatted as (734,343.54), and pressing "Comma style" would not do anything else. It seems that the issue doesn't have anything to do with the file format or manual/custom displays or formats. I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: I updated the code to not include any outside variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding *Local:=True* as a parameter to *.SaveAs* did the trick. From what I found:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel

> True saves files against the language of Microsoft Excel (including control panel settings). False (default) saves files against the language of Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) (which is typically US English unless the VBA project where Workbooks.Open is run from is an old internationalized XL5/95 VBA project).

It seems that this mostly applies to users who don't use English as the main language for Excel.